# How to set the cursor to any part of the text using TextFieldValue (w/ FocusRequester) on pressing/clicking the TextField

Tags: focus, cursor, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, text-cursor

I tried to look around but I can't find a way to

- force a `focus`,
- set the `cursor` to the end of text
- and still be able to set the `cursor` to any part of the text when
  pressing/clicking.

With `FocusRequester` the cursor is set to the start of text, but with `TextFieldValue(<text>, <range>)` I'm able to place the cursor at the end, the problem is that with this approach the cursor is always forced to any specified `selection = TextRange(<index>)`(*in my case its the end using the current length of the changing value* `onValueChange`), I have no idea how to set the `cursor` in any part (selection) when I press/click the `TextField`.

My Implementation:

```
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Some Text")) }

    Row (
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(150.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(selection = TextRange("Some Text".length))
            }
    ) {

        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = {
                textFieldValue =
                    textFieldValue.copy(text = it.text, selection = TextRange(it.text.length))
            },
        )
    }
```

And what I'm trying to achieve (Large text area with text set and starts from top-left), its entire part should be `clickable` and triggers `focus` for the text field, the reason why I wrapped it in a `Row` with a `clickable` modifier.

[image]

[image]

I wasn't able to achieve this with a single text field with specified height, as `TextAlign` doesn't have a Top-Start alignment